# Python ,TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting, SMB mount command

Tags: python, python-2.7, mount, smb, libsmbclient

I am trying to smb mount using below script but facing "TypeError" issue can someone please help me to solve this.
the actual command i want to execute is 
mount -t cifs //111.11.111.111/SMBShare /mnt  -o username=admin,password=admin,vers=3.0

python code:

#!/usr/bin/env python

```
 def setup_env(self, get_xyz_share):    
     share = get_xyz_share.name
     dx_ip = co.data_sols[0].address
     co.clients[0].execute(['mount' ,'-t' ,'cifs' ,'//%s','/','%s' ,'/mnt', '-o' ,'username=admin,password=admin,vers=3.0' %(dx_ip, share)])
```

The script output looks like :---

> ```
>   co.clients[0].execute(['mount' ,'-t' ,'cifs' ,'//%s','/','%s' ,'/mnt', '-o' ,'username=admin,password=admin,vers=3.0' %(dx_ip, share)])
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>   dx_ip      = '111.11.111.111'
>   get_xyz_share = <cx.models.Share.Shareobject at 0x4d53248 | name SMBShare>)
> self       = TestMySMB
> share      = 'SMBShare'
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You do the conversion on the last element in the list:

```
'username=admin,password=admin,vers=3.0' %(dx_ip, share)
```

Which has no %s at all.

you probably want to do something like:

```
co.clients[0].execute(['mount' ,'-t' ,'cifs' ,'//%s/%s' % (dx_ip, share) ,'/mnt', '-o' ,'username=admin,password=admin,vers=3.0'])
```

Comment: you're welcome. and if it solved your problem please be sure to accept the answer as the correct one